# SIGNALSEGV (segmentation fault) out of vector pushback method

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, singleton, stdvector, factory-method

I am making a shell using linux (WSL).
For some Unkown reason, when I pushback a struct pointer (that I made) into a vector it calls SIGNALSEGV.

These are the main classes of the problematic code,

```
class TimeoutCommand : public BuiltInCommand {
public:
    bool background;
    std::string line;
    int pid;
    int duration;
    TimeoutCommand(const char* cmd_line);  //prepare line
    virtual ~TimeoutCommand() {}
    void execute() override; ////set alarm + fork + add to joblist + add to timelist
};

class TimeoutList{

public:
    struct TimeoutEntry {
        std::string line;
        int pid;
        time_t start_time;
        int duration;
        TimeoutEntry(int pid,time_t start_time,std::string line,int duration)
        :pid(pid),start_time(start_time),line(line),duration(duration)
        {};
    };

std::vector<TimeoutEntry*> TimeoutVec;
TimeoutList();
~TimeoutList() {
    for (TimeoutEntry *entry : TimeoutVec)
        delete entry;
}
void addCommand(TimeoutCommand* cmd); ////add new timeout
void timeoutCheck(); ////timout timedoutcommands

};
```

This is TimeoutCommand constructor and the line that calls the problematic function:

```
    TimeoutCommand::TimeoutCommand(const char *cmd_line)
        :BuiltInCommand(cmd_line)
{
    _parseCommandLine(cmd_line,args);
    background=_isBackgroundComamnd(cmd_line);
    for(int i=2;args[i]!=NULL;i++) {
        line +=args[i];
    }
    duration=stoi(args[1]);
}
void TimeoutCommand::execute() {
    alarm(duration);
    **SmallShell::getInstance().timouts->addCommand(this);**
...
...
...
```

And finally here is the problematic fucntion:

```
void TimeoutList::addCommand(TimeoutCommand *cmd) {
time_t t= time(NULL);
if (t==-1){
    perror("smash error: time failed");
    return;
}
TimeoutEntry* entry = new TimeoutEntry(cmd->pid,t,cmd->line,cmd->duration);
**TimeoutVec.push_back(entry);**
```

}

What is causing the segmentation fault?
I dont see any wierd pointer messups or anything like that right away.

running this command woul look something like:
timeout 3 sleep 10

Which will be the cmd_line

This is the part from std::vector that causes the segfault

```
  push_back(const value_type& __x)
      {
    **if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)**
      {
        _GLIBCXX_ASAN_ANNOTATE_GROW(1);
        _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                     __x);
        ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
        _GLIBCXX_ASAN_ANNOTATE_GREW(1);
      }
    else
      _M_realloc_insert(end(), __x);
      }
```

**Problematic lines are marked with ** **

Comment: Any reason why it's `std::vector<TimeoutEntry*> TimeoutVec;` instead of `std::vector<TimeoutEntry> TimeoutVec;`? Or if you must use pointers: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TimeoutEntry>> TimeoutVec;`?

Comment: Not a particular reason i guess, just for semantics.

Comment: The reason why it makes a difference is that you would be removing the need for manual dynamic memory management, and thus remove a potential point of failure.  For each `new` call in your application, you need to carefully manage the memory.  If you simply had a `std::vector<TimeoutEntry>`, then no need to manually manage memory.  Then the line you say you're having issue with would simply be: `TimeoutVec.push_back({cmd->pid,t,cmd->line,cmd->duration});`, with no call to `new`.

Comment: It might be, but ive done some similiar things in other places in the code, and i delete everything in the desctrucor. and even if so i dont think it should be the caus of the seg fualt.

Comment: *but ive done some similiar things in other places in the code, and i delete everything in the desctrucor.* -- I hate to be the bearer of bad news to you, but C++ does not work this way.  It isn't looking at code and saying "I have x lines of calls to `new`, and I have `x` lines of calls to `delete`, so I'm ok".  Remember that there is a program flow going on, and you do not know or not sure how the code is flowing.  It isn't as simple as just counting up the number of `new` and `delete` calls in your source code.

Comment: The second thing is that the code you're showing is part of a class.  If those member functions are not static, that means that the code shown must be executed with a valid instance of `TimeoutList`.  We have no idea of that instance of `TimeoutList` is valid or not.  That's why a [mcve] should be posted.

Comment: your last comment helped me think of the issue, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i instialized a pointer to an instance of TimeoutList without allocating a new istance.