# linux kernel wont boot after task_struct changes

Tags: linux, kernel, gnu, init, boot

I have changed the task_struct on my linux kernel to add another Variable
Meaning changing the struct task_struct under include/linux/sched.h

```
/* weight new field*/
int weight;
/*
 * New fields for task_struct should be added above here, so that
 * they are included in the randomized portion of task_struct.
 */
randomized_struct_fields_end
```

In line 1135 of the sched.h

I want the value to be initialized to 0 for init so i also added the line:

weight= 0, /
in init_task.h as so:

> define INIT_TASK(tsk) 
> {                                   
> INIT_TASK_TI(tsk)                       
> .state      = 0,                        
> .stack      = init_stack,                   
> .usage      = ATOMIC_INIT(2),               
> .flags      = PF_KTHREAD,                   
> .prio       = MAX_PRIO-20,                  
> .static_prio    = MAX_PRIO-20,                  
> .normal_prio    = MAX_PRIO-20,                  
> .policy     = SCHED_NORMAL,                 
> .cpus_allowed   = CPU_MASK_ALL,                 
> .nr_cpus_allowed= NR_CPUS,                  
> .mm     = NULL,                     
> .active_mm  = &init_mm,                 
> .restart_block = {                      
> .fn = do_no_restart_syscall,                
> },                              
> .se     = {                     
> .group_node     = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.se.group_node),    
> },                              
> .rt     = {                     
> .run_list   = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.rt.run_list),  
> .time_slice = RR_TIMESLICE,             
> },                              
> .tasks      = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.tasks),            
> INIT_PUSHABLE_TASKS(tsk)                    
> INIT_CGROUP_SCHED(tsk)                      
> .ptraced    = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.ptraced),          
> .ptrace_entry   = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.ptrace_entry),     
> .real_parent    = &tsk,                     
> .parent     = &tsk,                     
> .children   = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.children),         
> .sibling    = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.sibling),          
> .group_leader   = &tsk,                     
> RCU_POINTER_INITIALIZER(real_cred, &init_cred),         
> RCU_POINTER_INITIALIZER(cred, &init_cred),          
> .comm       = INIT_TASK_COMM,               
> .thread     = INIT_THREAD,                  
> .fs     = &init_fs,                 
> .files      = &init_files,                  
> .signal     = &init_signals,                
> .sighand    = &init_sighand,                
> .nsproxy    = &init_nsproxy,                
> .pending    = {                     
> .list = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.pending.list),       
> .signal = {{0}}},                   
> .blocked    = {{0}},                    
> .alloc_lock = __SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED(tsk.alloc_lock),     
> .journal_info   = NULL,                     
> INIT_CPU_TIMERS(tsk)                        
> .pi_lock    = __RAW_SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED(tsk.pi_lock),    
> .timer_slack_ns = 50000, /* 50 usec default slack */        
> .pids = {                           
> [PIDTYPE_PID]  = INIT_PID_LINK(PIDTYPE_PID),        
> [PIDTYPE_PGID] = INIT_PID_LINK(PIDTYPE_PGID),       
> [PIDTYPE_SID]  = INIT_PID_LINK(PIDTYPE_SID),        
> },                              
> .thread_group   = LIST_HEAD_INIT(tsk.thread_group),     
> .thread_node    = LIST_HEAD_INIT(init_signals.thread_head), 
> .weight = 0,                        
> INIT_IDS                            
> INIT_PERF_EVENTS(tsk)                       
> INIT_TRACE_IRQFLAGS                     
> INIT_LOCKDEP                            
> INIT_FTRACE_GRAPH                       
> INIT_TRACE_RECURSION                        
> INIT_TASK_RCU_PREEMPT(tsk)                  
> INIT_TASK_RCU_TASKS(tsk)                    
> INIT_CPUSET_SEQ(tsk)                        
> INIT_RT_MUTEXES(tsk)                        
> INIT_PREV_CPUTIME(tsk)                      
> INIT_VTIME(tsk)                         
> INIT_NUMA_BALANCING(tsk)                    
> INIT_KASAN(tsk)                         
> INIT_LIVEPATCH(tsk)                     
> INIT_TASK_SECURITY                      
> }

For some reason my modified kernel doesnt boot.

[point where it gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WXdO.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REpN5.png)

In the init code there is a / after every line, stackoverflow just doesnt show it.

EDIT: I am recompiling the compiler after the changes and I do intend to change the kernelspace

Comment: Stack Overflow requires the error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as *image*. Please, copy paste the error message (and your other part of log) into the question post. See also [ask]. "In the init code there is a / after every line, stackoverflow just doesnt show it." - Proper formatting of the code is the **code formatting**, not a *blockquote* one. In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272498/signalsegv-segmentation-fault-out-of-vector-pushback-method) you have used the proper formatting.

Comment: The message "disagrees about version" in the kernel log suggests that you forgot to recompile **modules** after changing the kernel: `make modules`. Or you forgot to install these modules: `make modules_install`.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the task structure is one of those fundamental structures whose layout is also known to userspace.  After changing it you may have to rebuild the binutils and recompile the C library (at least).  That is such a big job that I'd probably just implement a parallel data structure so userspace wouldn't need to know about it.

Comment: i do intend on changing the kernelspace, and i am recompiling the kernel after every change

Answer (score 0):

I met and solved this problem yesterday . You may encounter this issue because many modules reference the task_struct structure. Therefore, when you modify task_struct, in addition to rebuilding the kernel itself, you'll also need to recompile other non-built-in modules and install them. You can do this with the following commands:

```
sudo make modules_install && make install
```